# <p:inputTextArea> does not shows the entered text properly

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using p:inputTextArea tag to autocomplete code as I am trying to make custom code editor. When I type and letter, the dropdown shows the respective suggestions.  That works fine. But the problem is if I type 'se' it may show house in the dropdown list. But when I select it the output will be 'seuse'. The first two letters of the word are replaced with the words that were typed by the user. 
what can I do in that case? 
Following is my XHTML file.

```
<h:form id="formId">
            <p:autoComplete  class="ui-auto" id="text1" value = "#{username.d}" 
                             completeMethod="#{dbConnect.completeArea}" queryDelay="1" minQueryLength="1">
                <f:converter converterId = "www" />
            </p:autoComplete>
            <br></br> 
            <h:commandButton  type="button" value = "submit" action = "t1" onclick="myFunction()"/>

            <br></br> <p:outputLabel for="text1" id="demo"></p:outputLabel> 

        </h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">

        const keywords = {
            IF: {style: "code-elem", indent: 4},
            ENDIF: {style: "code-elem", indent: -4},
            IFLISTING: {style: "code-str", indent: 4},
            ENDIFLISTING: {style: "code-str", indent: -4},
            VAR: {style: "code-comment", indent: 0},
            LISTING: {style: "code-comment", indent: 0}
        };

        function myFunction() {
            let indent = 0;
            document.getElementById('formId:demo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('formId:text1_input').value.split(/[\r\n]+/).map(line => {
                const oldIndent = indent;
                line = line.trim().replace(/###([A-Z]+)(.*?)###/g, (m, keyword, arg) => {
                    const param = keywords[keyword];
                    if (!param)
                        return m;
                    indent += param.indent;
                    return '<span class="' + param.style + '">' + m + '</span>';
                });
                return "&nbsp;".repeat(Math.min(indent, oldIndent)) + line;
            }).join("<br/>");
        }
        window.onload = myFunction;

    </script>
```

And if this is of any use, following is my java file too.

```
public List<String> completeArea(String inputName) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String query1 = "select name from labels where name like ? order by name";
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/company", "root", "");
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query1)) {
                pst.setString(1,"%" + inputName + "%");
                try (ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        result.add(rs.getString(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error occured" + ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I have edited my question as what @selaron said that p:autoComplete will not solve my issue.

Comment: What kind of use case do you want to implement? autoComplete is very different from textArea. What did you try so far? I don't think there's a simple attribute like "autosize" to set on the component. You likely have to use javaScript.

Comment: I want to use autocomplete tag but it should be the size of a textarea. I am making a custom code editor using primefaces and javascript.

Comment: I was using this so far.   <p:inputTextarea  id = "input" rows="10" cols="50" value = "#{username.d}"  
                             completeMethod="#{dbConnect.completeArea}" queryDelay="1" minQueryLength="1">
                <f:converter converterId = "www" />
            </p:inputTextarea>

Comment: What where the issues you encountered using textArea query functionality? p:autoComplete is used for single or multiple item selection, not for writing text. Are you sure p:autoComplete can solve your issues when having large size?

Comment: when I use p:inputTextArea, suppose I have (sunny, sought, summer) in my database. And I type 'ht' it will show only sought in the dropdown list, which is fine. But when I select it and press enter, the result would show 'htught'. I mean it replaces the first two letters typed with the actual word.

Comment: @Selaron Can you help me with this issue? I think we need to put some clear function which clears the typed letters and selects from the dropdown list.